# passar dois parametros via GET

Tags: php, html, pdo, input

Olá,
Estou com dúvida de como posso passar 2 parâmetro via GET, só que o segundo seria após a resposta do primeiro.
o que quero fazer é selecionar um item em um input select e atualizar a pagina com aquele parâmetro no GET e depois com base neste parâmetro vai habilitar um campo input text pra mim digitar algo que vai consultar no banco os 2 parâmetros juntos na clausula WHERE.

meu código atual:

```
if ( isset($_GET["revenda"])  ) {
$var1 = $_GET["revenda"];

$query = ("SELECT bem, des_bem, revenda FROM AFX_BEM WHERE revenda LIKE :imobilizado "); 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(':imobilizado', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();

}

if ( isset($_GET["bemdesc"])  ) {
$var1 = $_GET["revenda"];
$var2 = $_GET["bemdesc"];

$query = ("SELECT bem, des_bem, revenda FROM AFX_BEM WHERE revenda LIKE :rev AND des_bem LIKE :bd "); 
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt2->bindValue(':rev', '%' . $var1 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->bindValue(':bd', '%' . $var2 . '%', PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt2->execute();

}

<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="lista.php" method="get">
         <div class="form-group">
             <label for="revenda">Pesquisar</label>      

             <select class="form-control" name="revenda" style="width: 140px" onchange="this.form.submit();" >
                       <option value="" disabled selected><?php if(isset($_GET["revenda"]) ) { 
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 1 ) { echo "Piracicaba"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 2 ) { echo "Botucatu"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 3 ) { echo "São Manuel"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 4 ) { echo "Lençóis Paulista"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 5 ) { echo "Jaú"; }
                       if ( ($_GET["revenda"]) == 6 ) { echo "Ibitinga"; }



                       } else {  ?>Revenda <?php } ?></option>
                        <?php
                            $linha2 = $stmt2->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                            foreach($linha2 as $listar2){



                        ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $listar2["REVENDA"]; ?>">
                            <?php echo utf8_encode($listar2["RAZAO_SOCIAL"]);    ?>
                        </option>


                        <?php
                            }

                        ?>

                        </select>



            <?php if(isset($_GET["revenda"]) ) {
                $bemdesc = "teste";
            ?>

            <form action="lista.php?revenda='<?php echo $revenda ?>' " method="get">
             <input class="form-control" type="text" name="bemdesc" id="bemdesc" placeholder="BEM ou Descrição">
             <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>

            <?php
            }
            ?>
             </form>


         </div>
     </form>insira o código aqui
```

Comment: Você esta tentando enviar dois `<form>` com o mesmo `submit`? É isso que esta tentando fazer?

Comment: mesmo fechando um </form> em cima do outro qdo eu digito algo no segundo e submit o primeiro parâmetro some da url e só fica o novo

Comment: Tenta colocar tudo dentro do mesmo `form`

Comment: mesmo efeito.. a url apaga  o revenda=5 (/imobilizados/lista.php?revenda=5) e fica somente assim: /imobilizados/lista.php?bemdesc=mesa .. preciso juntar revenda=5&bemdesc=mesa

Answer (score 0):

Coloque dentro de apenas 1 `<form>` assim:

```
<form class="form-inline" role="form" action="lista.php" method="get">
<input type="text" name="texto1" value="textoDigitado1">
<input type="text" name="texto2" value="textoDigitado2">
<button type="submit"></button></form>
```

Dessa forma o resultado da url seria assim:

```
lista.php?texto1=textoDigitado1&texto2=textoDigitado2
```

Comment: eu preciso submeter o valor do select primeiro.. dai minha url vai ficar com 1 get.. após isso vai abrir um campo input pra mim submeter um segundo get do tipo text